# how to create a nutch job in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, nutch

hadoop jar apache-nutch-1.6.job org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl firstSite/urls -dir urls -depth 1 -topN 5

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: apache-nutch-1.6.job
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:90)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: apache-nutch-1.6.job (No such file or directory)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:88)
```

Answer (score 2):

The immediate answer is that your apache-nutch-1.6.job is missing or not in the current directory.

The Apache Nutch .job file (e.g. apache-nutch-1.9.job) is created in runtime/deploy/ when you compile nutch (via 'ant')  Note that you need the source distribution of apache-nutch, not the binary version, to create this file.

The .job file is actually a JAR file. It is significantly larger than apache-nutch-1.9.jar because it contains all dependencies (as well as files from conf/) within it, so that it contains everything needed to run a Hadoop job.